# Django image not getting uploaded into my 'media/user_profile_picture' folder

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

So , my website has a feature where user can upload an image of themselves for their profile picture when they register their account . The model for the same is as follows :

```
class Buyer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()
    dp = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_profile_picture/', blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='buyer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now for this model , I have made the following views to extract the relevant data (including images) from the form inside the template when the submit button is pressed

```
@login_required
def buyer_profile_details(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # creating the buyer object
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        state = request.POST.get('state')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        pincode = request.POST.get('pincode')
        # dp is the user submitted image which I want to get from the form
        dp = request.POST.get('dp')
        Buyer.objects.create(name=firstname, last_name=lastname, phone=phone, email=email, address=address,
                             city=city, state=state, pincode=pincode, dp=dp, created_by=request.user)
        UserType.objects.create(user_type=2, created_by=request.user)
        return redirect('my_profile')


    return render(request, 'new_buyer_profile_details.html', {})
```

And finally this is the template containing the form that I made for getting the image

```
<form class="block-register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col form-group">
                        <label>First name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="firstname" name="firstname">
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    <div class="col form-group">
                        <label>Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="lastname" name="lastname">
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                </div> <!-- form-row end.// -->

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="phone" name="email">
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                </div>


                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>City</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="city" name="city">
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>State</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="state" name="state">
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                </div>


                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Street</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="address" name="address">
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Pincode</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="pincode" name="pincode">
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Display Picture</label>
                        <input type="file" id="dp" name="dp" accept="image/*">
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                </div>





                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Register  </button>
                </div> <!-- form-group// -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked=""> <div class="custom-control-label"> I am agree with <a href="#">terms and contitions</a>  </div> </label>
                </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
            </form>
```

When I press submit , all data other than the image is getting stored for some reason . Why is my image not getting submitted ? When I add the image directly from admin panel of django , it gets stored properly to the media/user_profile_picture folder .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written this line to get the file from the POST data:

```
dp = request.POST.get('dp')
```

But files are **not** present in `request.POST` they are present in [`request.FILES` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) hence you want to change that line to:

```
dp = request.FILES.get('dp')
```

> **Note**: It is better to use a [`Form` class [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#the-form-class)
> (or a [`ModelForm` [Django
> docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform))
> when dealing with forms in Django as they will automatically clean and
> validate the form for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` file, you need to have the following specified to indicate where user-uploaded files will be stored:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

See the documentation for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/

Comment: I have specified that settings already . There is no issues with that . I have image uploading functionality in other parts of my website too and it is working perfectly there